# How to retrieve a row from SQLalchemy with flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am learning how to use SQLalchemy and databases in general with flask. I am following a tutorial and it uses the below classes and files.

```
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database
```

To show an inserted row in the database, the tutorial uses the following:

```
from app.models import User
>>> u = User(username='susan', email='susan@example.com')
>>> u
<User susan>
```

My problem is that I can not display the same output. I mean when I code the the statement, I get an error

> from app.models import User
> ImportError: No module named app.models

Please let me know how to adapt the posted code so I can retrieve data from database

**Folder Structure**:

```
d:\xxx\xxx\db1\app\models
d:\xxx\xxx\db1\__init__
d:\xxx\xxx\db1\config
```

** **init** **:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

**config**:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
# ...
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**models**:

```
from app import db
from app.models import User

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primaty_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

Comment: add your folder/files structure to the question.

Comment: @waynetech I have not thought that the folder structure matters..I will do it

Comment: @waynetech i added the folder structure

Comment: move `__init__.py` in `d:\xxx\xxx\db1\app\` folder

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import **User** on the same module where models is declared, so I don't think If you need that second line in models.py, Try commenting and see what happens

```python
from app import db
from app.models import User ## I think the problems is 

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primaty_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

Comment: I believe the OP's issue was the missing __init__.py in app/models.